# Why doesn't if [ echo $foo | grep -q bar ] work?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read user input and compare it against a stored value as follows:

```
read confirm
if [ echo $confirm | grep -q y ]; then
  ...
fi
```

However, this results in a pair of errors:

```
[: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

Why does this happen, and what's the appropriate alternative?

Comment: `[ ]` is not part of `if` syntax. Just use `if echo "$confirm" | grep -q y`.

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22726/10454) on [unix.se] and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22728/10454).

Comment: ...I've tried to improve the question: Code samples should be minimum needed to reproduce a question and nothing more; and titles should be specific enough to make it clear to a someone with the same problem whether a question and its answers will be helpful to them.

Comment: ^That's fine, I figured I'd add more context. I've had people downvote me for not having enough code.

Comment: *nod* -- it needs to be enough code to reproduce a problem, so not enough code is a possible problem as well. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://sscce.org/ are good places to help figure out where that line is.

Comment: BTW, http://www.shellcheck.net/ catches this one, issuing the following (relevant and correct) recommendation: "Use `if cmd; then ..` to check exit code, or `if [[ $(cmd) == .. ]]` to check output.".

Comment: ...as another aside: Quotes are important. If `confirm='*'`, then `echo $confirm` will actually emit a list of filenames in the current directory, whereas `echo "$confirm"` will emit that `*` as a literal, and thus accurately represent your user input. That's another thing http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short Answer

For your immediate use case, you simply want:

```
if echo "$confirm" | grep -q y; then
```

...or its much more efficient equivalent (if your shell is bash):

```
if [[ $confirm = *y* ]]; then
```

...or its much more efficient equivalent (for *any* POSIX shell):

```
case $confirm in *y*) echo "Put your code for the yes branch here" ;; esac
```

#### Why was the original wrong?

`[` is not part of `if` syntax: `if` simply takes a (potentially compound) command as its argument before the `then`. `[` is different name for the `test` command, which runs checks on its arguments; however, if what you want to test is the *exit status* of `grep -q`, then the `test` command doesn't need to be invoked for this purpose at all.

If you put a `|` inside a `[` command, that makes your compound command a pipeline, and starts a new simple command. Arguments after the `|` are thus no longer passed to `[`.

With your original code:

```
if [ echo $confirm | grep -q y ]; then
```

...this was running two commands, with a pipeline between them:

```
[ echo $confirm # first command
grep -q y ]     # second command
```

Since `[` requires that its last argument be `]`, it reported that that mandatory argument was missing; and since `grep` treats extra arguments as filenames to read, it complained that no file named `]` could be found.

Also, `[ "$foo" ]` checks whether the contents of `foo` is nonempty. Since the output of `grep -q` is *always* empty, `[ "$(echo "$confirm" | grep -q y)" ]`, while syntactically correct, would always evaluate to false, even while *exit status* of `grep -q` changes to indicate whether a match was found. (`[ "$(echo "$confirm" | grep y)" ]`, by contrast, is an alternative that emits a correct result - using `[ ]` to test whether the output from `grep` is or is not empty -- but is much less efficient than the best-practice approaches).

---

#### Formal `if` syntax

From `help if`:

> `if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi`
>
> The `if COMMANDS` list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
>      `then COMMANDS` list is executed.  Otherwise, each `elif COMMANDS` list is
>      executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding
>      `then COMMANDS` list is executed and the if command completes.  Otherwise,
>      the `else COMMANDS` list is executed, if present.  The exit status of the
>      entire construct is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero
>      if no condition tested true.

Notably, `if` takes a list of COMMANDS, and no `[` is included in the syntax specification.

Comment: I don't necessarily need grep here, but the rest of the code starts using a similar condition to check of certain sets of characters are in a string. I'm going to take a look at the test command. This has been really informative.

Comment: `[[ ]]`, which is a bash extension, supports glob-style pattern matching as opposed to just string comparisons provided by standard test. Thus, if you want to find out if, say, either `m` or `o` is in a string, you can use `[[ $string = *[mo]* ]]`. If I understand your above content, that might be the tool for the job at hand. (`case` also supports glob-style pattern matching, so you can do similar things even while being compatible with all POSIX shells).

Comment: ...and if you *really* need a regex, consider `[[ $str =~ $re ]]`, which evaluates `$str` against `$re`, with the latter interpreted as an ERE-style regex (the same syntax used by `grep -E` or `egrep`).

Comment: Is (using double square brackets like that) it case sensitive?

Comment: By default, yes, but that's a configurable option. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern, which goes into detailed documentation, including the `nocasematch` option.